# Extracting the body from HTTP post requestH

Tags: java, http, post, request, server

I have a weird problem when trying to extract the body of a given
HTTP post request.

If I try to extract only the header, it works fine. When I try to extract the body, the method blocks (even thought the stream still has data in it).

Here is my code:

```
private void extractHeader() throws Exception {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

    boolean extractBody = false;
    int bodyLength = 0;
    String line;

    while (!(line = bufferedReader.readLine()).equals("")) {
        buffer.append(line + "");
        if (line.startsWith("POST")) {
            extractBody = true;
        }
        if (line.startsWith("Content-Length:")) {
            bodyLength = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1, line.length()));
        }
    }
    requestHeader = buffer.toString();

    if (extractBody) {
        char[] body = new char[bodyLength];
        reader.read(body, 0, bodyLength);
        requestBody = new String(body);
    }
}
```

And this is the request request:

```
POST /params_info.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8080/index.html
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 31

firstname=Mickey&lastname=Mouse
```

From what I understand, the loop will go until seeing the empty string 
and then stoping. At this stage, the reader can read 'Content-Length' number of bytes. So it should have no problem reading the body and finish. Instead, it blocks on the line 'reader.read(body, 0, bodyLength);'
(The reason I don't use readLine() is because body does not end with \n).

I've tried debugging it in al kinds of ways but I get nothing. Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Lets assume that bodyLength has some value greater than 0 for now.
I did not had any problems when extracting only the header when using the empty string "" instead of /r/n.

In this case, When the loop ends after reading the empty line (that part works) it should have no problem reading x characters from the stream (x = content-length), yet it simply blocks when activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the header using the `bufferedReader`:

```
while (!(line = bufferedReader.readLine()).equals("")) {
```

but read the body using `reader`, which has no data available, as this has been read and buffered by the `bufferedReader`:

```
    reader.read(body, 0, bodyLength);
```

Change that line to

```
    bufferedReader.read(body, 0, bodyLength);
```

Comment: Works!! Thank you!!!

Can you please explain what 'exhausted' means in the context of stream readers?

Comment: You're welcome! Updated the wording to hopefully be more clear.